# How to combine gcc flags -o and -MM correctly?

Tags: gcc, dependencies, linker-errors

During compilation and linking of a simple program, I encountered a weird behavior of `gcc` that I cannot explain.

This here works perfectly fine for me

```
cc -Wall -c -o obj/main.o src/main.c
cc -Wall -c -o obj/foo.o src/foo.c
cc -Wall -o bin/program obj/main.o obj/foo.o
```

However, once I ask `gcc` to create and store dependency information in a separate file, the linker throws an error:

```
cc -MM -MP -MF deps/main.d -Wall -c -o obj/main.o src/main.c
cc -MM -MP -MF deps/foo.d -Wall -c -o obj/foo.o src/foo.c
cc -Wall -o bin/program obj/main.o obj/foo.o
# obj/main.o: file not recognized: File truncated
# collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I expect `gcc` to write the dependency information in the file provided with the -MF statement. In seems that the object files are somehow modified such that the linker cannot read them anymore.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object files are truncated to 0 bytes as a side-effect of the preprocessor option `-MM`

Refer to [the documentation of GCC's preprocessor options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options)
and you see that `-MM` has the same effect as `-M`, except that dependency rules are not generated with respect to any system headers
`#include`-ed by the translation unit.

For the `-M` option, you will see:

> Instead of outputting the result of preprocessing, output a rule suitable for make describing the dependencies of the main source file...

And also:

> Passing -M to the driver implies -E...

And turning to option `-E` you will see:

> If you use the -E option, nothing is done except preprocessing.

(That is actually a bit sloppy. Really it should read: "If you use the -E option, no **translation** is done except preprocessing.")

The `-o filename` option specifies that whatever kind of output file is requested - preprocessed code, assembly, object code or binary - it shall be written to `filename`.

So, for example, the command

```
cc -MM -MP -MF deps/main.d -Wall -c -o obj/main.o src/main.c
```

instructs the compiler (among other things) to:-

- Perform no translation beyond preprocessing (by implied `-E`).
- Don't output the result of preprocessing; output a dependency rule instead (by `-MM`)
- Don't write the dependency rule to the output file (`obj/main.o`); write to it `deps/main.d` instead (by `-MF deps/main.d`)

As a result, the output file `obj/main.o` is clobbered and opened to receive the output of
preprocessing; there *is* no output of preprocessing; the generated dependency rule is written to
`deps/main.d`, and when the command completes `obj/main.o` is closed containing 0 bytes. The same
thing happens to `obj/foo.o`.

This is not what you want to happen, of course. The options `-M` and `-MM` are useful only for generating
dependency files independently of compilation. But you want a command to generate a dependency file
`deps/<name>.d` *and* to proceed with translation all the way to object code, output in `obj/<name>.o`

To do what you want, replace the option `-MM` with `-MMD` in your commands. In the documentation you'll see:

> -MD
>
> -MD is equivalent to -M -MF file, except that -E is not implied... **Since -E is not implied, -MD can be used to generate a dependency output file as a side effect of the compilation process.**
>
> -MMD
>
> Like -MD except mention only user header files, not system header files.

[my emphasis]